# Show which objects are alive at app close Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

is there a way to make visual studio 2013 to show which objects are alive when I close the app in debugging mode? Before the object dump starts and in the readable format (not memory adresses but object names). The problem is that I have this big project and I wasn't writing destructors (I was telling myself that I'll do that later) well now is later and I somehow can't tell which objects needs to destroy properly. All I have is a lot of Live objects when I close the app. So if there was a way to show the names (or better types) of objects that are alive that would be very helpful.

PS: I am sorry if something like that already is here but I could not find anything.

PSS: I know bad practice not to write destructors ... from now on I'll write them right away.

Comment: Variables only have names in the source code, and the type is not available at runtime, so you can't. If you have live objects when your application exits you have created them dynamically (with `new`) and forgot to destroy them. It's only tangentially related to having destructors. It's not bad practice not to write destructors, if your objects don't need them. The *best* practice is to write classes that don't need destructors.

Comment: No need to display anything. It won't help you anyway. If you leave out the destructor for class A only, you may well get leaked objects of types B to Z inclusively. You need to properly destroy all objects. "All" as in "no exceptions". Not every class needs a user-defined destructor, but it's your responsibility to verify that this is the case for each individual class.

Comment: @molbdnilo yeah thats it ... I want to use destructors to delete those dynamically created objects inside other classes, I guess I am just looking for reasons not to start writing those things ... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about such functionality, but IMHO you don't need it:

1. Even if you will know those alive objects, you couldn't determine parent objects and destructors where those alive object should be destroyed
2. Destroy alive objects is not so important on app closing, because OS will clean all alive objects automatically (although, it is not always appropriate).

So I think it will be better just to start writing destructors for all objects which have constructors or dynamically allocated resources. Each destructor will improve your already working app.

Comment: Yeah, maybe you are right. I better stop being lazy and start writing the required destructors and stop looking for shortcuts ... I will have to write almost all the destructors anyway so .... thanks
And yeah I know that OS will clean everything it's only that when I close app in debug in visual studio I get tons of messages about the live objects and thats not nice so I am going to write those destructors.

Comment: Right decision! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**Object Lifetime View**

- The Object Lifetime view is available when Also collect .NET object lifetime data is checked on the Performance Session property pages.
- The garbage collector of the .NET Framework manages the allocation and release of memory for your application. To optimize the performance of the garbage collector, the managed heap is divided into three generations: 0, 1, and 2. The garbage collector of the runtime stores new objects in generation 0. Objects that survive collections are promoted and stored in generations 1 and 2.
- The garbage collector reclaims memory by deallocating a whole generation of objects. For objects that were created by the profiled application, the Object Lifetime view displays the number and size of the objects and the generation in which they are reclaimed.

**Instance Data**

- Instance data indicates the number of objects of the type that were created in the profiling run, and the generation in which the objects were deallocated by the garbage collector.
- You can view the Instances which are not deallocated until the end of the profiling run.

Source : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242731(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: This seems to be specifically for Managed .Net applications. You can do memory profiling with native applications though (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/04/02/diagnosing-memory-issues-with-the-new-memory-usage-tool-in-visual-studio.aspx)